# making toast in an activity and showing it in another one

Tags: android, toast, countdowntimer

I have a class extends countdowntimer

i want to make a toast in onfinish(),which shows up every time the onfinish() function called from any other class in any object instantiated from it

how can i do that ?

```
package com.fawzyx.exams_countdowntimer;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CountDown extends CountDownTimer {

    public CountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
/*
millisInFuture : The number of millis in the future from the call to start() until the countdown is done and onFinish() is called.
countDownInterval : The interval along the way to receive onTick(long) callbacks.

*/


    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: use getApplicationContext() instead of specific context

Comment: pass the activity context to the constructor of that class and use it there to display toast

Comment: Show us what you have done and the error.

Comment: show the code and logcat

Comment: @Raghunandan

sorry didnt get your answer

Comment: @vipulmittal
ok i will add the code in the question

Comment: `new MyClass(ActivityName.this)` Now in constructor `Context context public MyClass(Context context){this.context=context }` . Noe use context to display toast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the context to the CounteDown class

```
new CountDown(MyActivityName.this,otherparams);
```

Now use the context passed to display the toast

```
Context context;
public CountDown(Context context,long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
this.context = context;
}
```

Then in `onFinish()`

```
Toast.makeText(context," Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class CountDown extends CountDownTimer {

    private Context context;

    public CountDown(Context context, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(context ,"Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You need to pass in a `Context` e.g. as a constructor arg:

   ```
   private Context mContext;

   public CountDown(Context context, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
       super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
       mContext = context;
   ```

   Pass in this `mContext` to the `Toast`.
2. After `Toast.makeText()`, call `show()` to actually display it.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
public class CountDown extends CountDownTimer {

   Context context;
    public CountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval , Context ctx) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

  this.context = ctx;

/*
millisInFuture : The number of millis in the future from the call to start() until the countdown is done and onFinish() is called.
countDownInterval : The interval along the way to receive onTick(long) callbacks.

*/
 }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(context ,"Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Call its `construtor` while the calling `Activity`context wherever we want countdown class

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this is to overwrite the `onStop` and use `getApplicationContext()`. Then the toast will appear when the activity closes.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast message here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```